# WebEngineView variables 'canGoBack' and 'canGoForward' returns wrong values

Tags: qt, qml, qwebengineview

I'm working on an application that's  running on Raspberry Pi 4, and I got this strange behavior of QML's WebEngineView.

I created 3 buttons for going to the main page and for going back and forward:

```
  Button {
        id: box_button_main_page
        text: "Go to Main Page"
        onClicked: mainWebView.url = "https://www.youtube.com/"
    }
    Button {
        id: box_button_go_back
        enabled: mainWebView.canGoBack
        text: "Back"
        onClicked: mainWebView.goBack()
    }

    Button {
        id: box_button_go_forward
        enabled: mainWebView.canGoForward
        text: "Forward"
        onClicked: mainWebView.goForward()
    }
```

It works as expected: the "Back" and "Forward" buttons become grayed at the right points. But, if one makes below actions:

- go to any link
- go to yet another link
- click "Back" button
- click "Go to Main Page"

then both "Back" and "Forward" buttons are still enabled. And clicking on "Forward" button does nothing.

I checked in the "Go to Main Page" `onClicked` action that both `canGoBack` and `canGoForward` returns `true` after setting `url` property. I tried to search if there is yet another method to order WEV to switch to another page, but there is none :(.

I didn't find on the Net anyone reporting it as a bug, so either I'm doing it wrong, or I actually found a bug >_>

Comment: I've created a bugreport. Maybe you can write the functionality yourself by using the `navigationHistory` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with `WebAction`. Have a look at this [demo](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/tree/examples/webengine/webengineaction?h=5.15). All I've done is add the following `Button` in the `ToolBar` `RowLayout`:

```
Button {
    text: "Go to Main Page"
    onClicked: webEngineView.url = "https://www.youtube.com/"
}
```

[image]

---

Here is a full example using `WebAction`:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtWebEngine 1.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("WebEngineAction Example")

    header: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent

            Button {
                text: "Go to Main Page"
                onClicked: webEngineView.url = "https://www.youtube.com/"
            }

            Button {
                property int itemAction: WebEngineView.Back
                text: "Back"
                enabled: webEngineView.action(itemAction).enabled
                onClicked: webEngineView.action(itemAction).trigger()
            }

            Button {
                property int itemAction: WebEngineView.Forward
                text: "Forward"
                enabled: webEngineView.action(itemAction).enabled
                onClicked: webEngineView.action(itemAction).trigger()
            }
        }
    }

    WebEngineView {
        id: webEngineView
        url: "https://qt.io"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: It took us long to response and in the mean time our team found another solution, but your solution is MUCH better. Thanks!